# Can't use the nameserver domain after installing cPanel/WHM

Tags: domain-name-system, centos6

I have a VPS with Linode (CentOS 6.0 64bit), I  just installed cPanel/WHM and though i only have 1 IP, i setup custom nameservers `ns1.mydomain.com`, `ns2.mydomain.com` both pointed to the same IP and it works.,

I pointed my other domains to `ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com`

I can access all the domains without any problem, The problem is i have created a new account for `mydomain.com` as well but i cannot access it.., I have pointed the nameservers correctly.. The error i get is "Server not found"

Is there any way to fix this?

My hostname is `cloud.mydomain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you setup the correct glue records for ns1 and ns2.mydomain.com?

thats more than likely the reason why.

"Server not found" means your browser could not make a dns lookup or the lookup failed, try looking at http://whatsmydns.net or http://dnscheck.pingdom.com/ to resolve the dns issues

I should point out that its poor practice to run both your Nameservers on a single server, and some registrars even prevent you registering nameservers to the same IP completely

Comment: I know that, but i want to use custom nameservers, not that i really need to use custom nameservers but it looks good.., Is there any other way to use custom nameservers without actually hosting our own DNS?

Comment: you can use custom nameservers while hosting your domain on them... its called glue records, otherwise put your nameserver domain on seperate dns servers and manage them from there